# I'm trying to compile the latest kernel from source but I am getting an error

Tags: kernel, compiling

So I am following this guide: http://kernelnewbies.org/OPWfirstpatchSetup

I followed the steps and installed the kernel from source. When I boot into the new kernel, Ubuntu loads up but then I only get a black screen.

Here is the end of the output I got from running `sudo make modules_install install`:

```
  DEPMOD  3.17.0-rc6+
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.17.0-rc6+ arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-rc6+ (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.38/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.17.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-rc6+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3
done
```

It looks like I have an error. Here is end of the output of /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.38/build/make.log:

```
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.fwinst obj=firmware __fw_modbuild
NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
 nvidia.ko failed to build!
make[2]: *** [nvidia.ko] Error 1
```

Unfortunately, `make.log` is a 23 megabyte file so I can't share all of it.

Here is make.log zipped if anyone wants to check it out: http://www.filedropper.com/makelog

How can I fix this error so that I can compile the kernel successfully so that I can run it on my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel compiled and installed successfully, only the nvidia driver failed to compile, most probably because it is not compatible with that version of the kernel. If you want the nvidia driver with your new kernel, you will have to find and install a more recent version of it.

Comment: Does it matter if I use the open source or proprietary driver? I am using the proprietary driver.

Comment: I am not familar with nvidia drivers, but you can always try to boot your new kernel and see if it works for you.